# Adjusting spacing in a list containing icon and text in HTML

Tags: html, list, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

Whenever I've to use a long section name inside a container with a list for a small column (col-2). My text is getting beneath my fontawesome icon as shown below. Thanks in advance!

[image]

PFB the HTML code:

```html
<ul class="js-scroll-nav list-group list-group-transparent list-group-flush list-group-borderless py-3 px-3">
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#online">
      <i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; List Item Apple Strudel
    </a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#discourses"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; List Item PumpkinStrudel
                                </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#disciple"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; List Item BerryStrudel</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#yogic"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; List Item CokeStrudel</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#events"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; List Item DoritosStrudel</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I leave space below fontawesome icon so that my text on the second line populates exactly below from where my first text starts as shown below:
[image: b]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `&nbsp;` for spacing. Use padding/margin as appropriate.

What we want to do here is set the `a` element to have `position:relative` and the icon to be positioned absolutely within it. Then in the `a` element we set the left padding appropriately to indent the text.

Adjust the values below to taste. Perhaps add your own classes instead of overriding bootstrap classes directly.

```css
a.list-group-item-action {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group-item-action i.fas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}

.list-group {
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="js-scroll-nav list-group list-group-transparent list-group-flush list-group-borderless py-3 px-3">
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#online">
      <i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>List Item Apple Strudel
    </a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#discourses"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>List Item PumpkinStrudel
                                </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#disciple"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>List Item BerryStrudel</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#yogic"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>List Item CokeStrudel</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action font-weight-medium mb-0 mb-md-2" href="#events"><i class="fas fa-play-circle  fa-lg"></i>List Item DoritosStrudel</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```